# Merge 2 data table according to a slightly different column

Tags: r

I have 2 data table and I want to merge them according to some overlap in a column. I was thinking to do something like

df_3 <- merge(x = df_1, y = df_2, all = TRUE, by.x = "Loci Start", by.y = "Start")

However I have a little problem because the column I want to merge with, has a slightly different format.

head(df_1)

```
Category Chromosome Loci Start  Loci End         Gene ID   Gene Symbol Strand Distance to TSS
1   Intron      chr10  047322187 047324337 ENST00000581492          GDF2      +             772
2    5'UTR      chr11  064210702 064211489 ENST00000541252        FERMT3      +            3278
3   Intron      chr11  128685393 128686512 ENST00000572256 RP11-744N12.3      -             476
4   Intron      chr11  128692708 128693199 ENST00000608303          FLI1      +            6418
5   Intron      chr12  005989201 005989836 ENST00000261405           VWF      -          135157
6   Intron      chr12  006036674 006037359 ENST00000261405           VWF      -           87659
```

head(df_2)

```
  Chromosome     Start       End n_of_interactions stats
1      chr10  47322187  47324337                12  9.68
2      chr11  64210702  64211489                10  7.63
3      chr11 128685393 128686512                12  6.01
4      chr11 128692708 128693199                10  6.51
5      chr12   5989201   5989836                17  5.51
6      chr12   6036674   6037359                11  7.19
```

`df_1$Loci Start` and `df_2$Start` are basically the same number but in `df_1` there are starting 0s to top up to 9 digits. Do you have any suggestion to get around this problem?

Thanks

Comment: What is the data type of Loci Start? If it is numeric then leading zeros will be removed automatically.

Comment: great!! I didn't know that. sorted in a really easy way!
Thanks a lot!

Comment: this seems easy to solve with leading zeroes... if this is not the case, try the functions from the `fuzzyjoin`-package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `str_pad` from `stringr` package to add 0 on left side of `Start` and convert it to char, then merge

Answer (score 2):

You could create a matching column in both datasets which contains loci.start/start as a numeric vector; that will strip away the leading 0's. So

```
df_1$merge <- as.numeric(df_1$['Loci Start'])
df_2$merge <- as.numeric(df_2$Start)
df_3 <- merge(x = df_1, y = df_2, all = TRUE, by = 'merge')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do (remove leading zeros):

```
df_1['Loci Start'] = gsub(pattern = '.*0', replacement = '', df_1['Loci Start'])
```

Then, do merge:

```
df_3 <- merge(x = df_1, y = df_2, all = TRUE, by.x = "Loci Start", by.y = "Start")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted a to be able use piping/`tidyverse`, you could do something like this.

```
library(tidyverse)

df_1 %>%
 mutate(`Loci Start` = as.numeric(`Loci Start`)) %>%
 left_join(df_2, by = c("Loci Start" = "Start")) # change for the type of join you want
```